# On the proof of Gagliardo–Nirenberg inequality

Tags: inequalities

Is there anyone checked on the paper Detailed proof of classical Gagliardo-Nirenberg interpolation inequality with historical remarks by A. Fiorenza, etc. carefully? In part 3.2 Proof of Theorem 1.2 of it, I wonder what if the L^p norm of the derivative of u is infinity at the first place, since if so, the last step of the argument seems to be invalid...
[image]

Comment: Are you asking, whether it is possible for $\|\nabla u\|_p = \infty$, $\|\nabla^{k+1}u\|_p < \infty$, and $\|u\|_{p} < \infty$?

Comment: Typically these types of inequalities are proven for smooth functions and then passed to Sobolev functions by density/continuity. For smooth functions the norms involved are always finite.

Comment: Yes, I wonder what happens if it is assumed initially that $\|Du\|_p=\infty$, $\|D^{k+1}u\|_r<\infty$ and $\|u\|_q<\infty$. And, for a test function $u\in C^{\infty}_{c}$, the argument holds of course. But, if there is a sequence of test functions $\{u_n\}$ such that $u_n$ tends to $u$ both in $W^{k+1,r}$ and $L^q$, then is the statement "$\|Du\|_p<\infty$  and $u_n$ tends to $u$ in $W^{1,p}$" true?

Comment: yes. the sequence of functions $u_n$ is Cauchy in both $W^{k+1,r}$ and $L^q$ by assumption, and being test functions the GN inequality holds for them, so that $u_n$ is also Cauchy in $W^{1,p}$; so it has a unique $W^{1,p}$ limit. The next step depends on how you define $W^{1,p}$. If you define it as a subset of the set of distributions, then you use that $W^{1,p}$ convergence implies convergence as distributions and since the limit is unique in distributions this limit must equal $u$ (as a distribution), and so we can identify the two.

Comment: If you define $W^{1,p}$ by completions of smooth functions, then as $u$ and this new limit object in $W^{1,p}$ are generated by the same set of Cauchy sequences, we can choose to identify them as the same object.

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thank you so much. I've been silly on such a exercise-leveled problem...